# Two feedforward propagation needed for a single weight update in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, it seems that we have to propagate the input to the top layer once to compute the current training error, and propagate another time to do the parameter update.

At the bottom of [the Tensorflow MNIST example](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.md), the line:

```
train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
```

was used to compute accuracy, which required a feedforward process.

Next, the line

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

was used to update the weight parameters. I think this process also requires a feedforward propagation first to get the network output so that the mean squared error can be calculated for back-propagation algorithm.

Do we really need to go through the whole network twice to get current training error and update parameters???

Answer (score 2):

No need to go through twice.  Check out the other examples, such as [mnist/convolutional.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py):

```
_, l, lr, predictions = s.run(
          [optimizer, loss, learning_rate, train_prediction],
          feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

You pull both nodes at the same time in run, and get both the training done and the train prediction at the same time.  This is the standard way of training.

In general, I'd suggest checking out the examples in models/ first.  The "red pill" and "blue pill" examples are meant to be a very gentle introduction to tensorflow, but the examples in models are a bit more real.  They're not production, but they're closer to what you'd want to do.